# Build connection with HaskellDB.HDBC.Odbc

Tags: haskell, odbc, hdbc, haskelldb

I'm new to Haskell. I've read most of LYAH and RWH and have also done some small programms. No I would like to use Haskell with an Oracle DB. I would like to use HaskellDB with HDBC.ODBC.

I was able to connect to the DB via HDBC and run a query. But I don't know how to connect via HaskellDB and ODBC. I can't find an example.

Answer (score 0):

You connect with the `odbcConnect` function in the `[haskelldb-hdbc-opbc][1]` package.

Here is at its source:

```
odbcConnect :: MonadIO m => SqlGenerator -> [(String,String)] -> (Database -> m a) -> m a
odbcConnect gen opts = hdbcConnect gen (connectODBC conninfo)
    -- strangely enough, mysql+unixodbc want a semicolon terminating connstring
    where conninfo = foldr (\(k,v) z -> k ++ "=" ++ v ++ ";" ++ z) [] opts
```

There we can see that it calls out to `connectODBC` which you know how to use already. The difference is that here we take a list of pairs of `(OptionName,OptionValue)` rather than a simple string, and those options get rendered as `key=value;` pairs in the connection string passed to `connectODBC`.